# Troubleshooting 'NullPointerException' in Spring Boot Application during Hibernate Entity Persistence

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, entity-framework, jpa

I'm working on a Spring Boot application where I'm using Hibernate for database persistence. However, I'm encountering a persistent NullPointerException that occurs when attempting to save an entity to the database using the save() method from my repository.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```java
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private double price;

    // Getters, setters, and other properties...
}

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}

@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public void saveProduct(Product product) {
        productRepository.save(product); // NullPointerException occurs here
    }
}
```

I've ensured that the Product object being passed to the saveProduct() method is not null, and all the necessary annotations are in place for Hibernate entity mapping. However, I'm still facing this issue consistently.

What could be causing this NullPointerException during the save() operation? Are there any common pitfalls or misconfigurations related to Hibernate entity persistence that I might be overlooking? How can I further investigate and troubleshoot this problem effectively?

I've read through several Hibernate and Spring Boot documentation pages and tried searching for similar issues on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found a solution that works for my case. Any insights or suggestions to point me in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If the NPE occurs in the line `productRepository.save(product);` then the only possibility is that `productRepository` is `null`. So it looks like your autowiring doesn't correctly initialize the repository. - (If the NPE would occur inside the save method your stacktrace would point you to the line in that method.)

Comment: Can you please attach stack trace?